# Choose an aggregate function for Group BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query like this:

```
Select Count(*) as TotalCount, Object2_ID, Object_ID, Object_Description
from Table1 
inner join table2 on...  
Group BY Object2_ID, Object_ID
```

I can't run this query because the column `Object_Description` isn't in `GROUP BY` or under aggregate function. `Object_Description` is a text column. I need any value of `Object_Description`. Now I use `MAX(Object_Description)` because it gives me right results, because `Object_Description` is the same for each group.

I can use `MAX()` or `MIN()` etc. - I will get right results in my query.

The question is - what is the most sufficient way to do this ?

I think that `MAX()` or `MIN()` produces small overheads.

Comment: Post your schema for those tables.

Comment: I think it is not necessary to answer on this question, isn't it? My real Query contains 5 tables and a lot of conditions. I wrote simplified information.

Answer (score 4):

You can get Object Description later, after calculation quantity (assumed that description in in table1 and you need get count from Table2):

```
SELECT Object_Id, Object_Description, Qty
FROM
( 
  SELECT Object_Id, Count(*) Qty
  FROM Table2
  GROUP BY Object_Id
) t 
JOIN Table1 t2 on t2.Object_Id = t.Object_Id
```

Comment: Do you really think that additional select and additional join (in my case  - several millions of rows in table) produces less overheads then MAX() on text columns....

Comment: @mmcteam.com.ua: only one way to find this out: **profile it!** with your own data, your own tables, your own server.

Comment: @marc_s:I've already profiled. I suppose to answer like it is exist an aggregate function as ANY() or another variant. Also I know about the solution @Michael provided. Also there is more efficient way to add Object_Description in Group By and I'll get right results as well. I'm looking for the solution with best performance. Michael's solution is worse then even I provided in the post. I'm looking for another one or some link to explanation of advantages/disadvantages of the approaches.

Comment: @mmcteam.com.ua, if you provide schema for your tables used in query it will be quite helpful for us (or at least execution plan). Otherwise we are discussing quite abstract thing.

Comment: @mmcteam: the solution you gave does not work. How is it relevant that it performs faster?

Comment: @RedFilter if you read once more my post you can understand what query I used. I used not directly code snippet, but with MAX on column Object_Description.